# Unable to Locate Textbox Element using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I am having trouble to send text to textbox present in the given image as I have tried by passing the xpath of that textbox but its generates an error mentioned below. Anyone that can help me out of that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

```
import time
path=r"path to your chrome driver.exe"
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/internet/#/contenido/index.html")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/button'))
         )
    element.click()
    print("prints its working fine now ..")
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="titulo"]/div[8]/i'))
         )
    element.click()
   
    search =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input').click()
    search.send_keys("somehting in text")
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
    search_1 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
    search_1.send_keys("somehting in text")
    search_1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    search_2 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
    search_2.send_keys("somehting in text")
    search_2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    print("Its also working now ......")
    
    time.sleep(3)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the **Comuna** input, there are some rules, since it has autocomplete functionality.

1 You have to define some specific value, which present in the list.

[image]

*Some random text will not work!*

2 You have to confirm the input with `Keys.ENTER`(`Keys.RETURN` on Mac).

```py
# explicit wait for visibility (max timeout - 60 seconds)
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input'))
)
search.send_keys("EL MONTE" + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
search_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
search_1.send_keys("somehting in text")

search_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
search_2.send_keys("somehting in text")

print("Its also working now ......")

time.sleep(3)
```

For other inputs, any text will be applied with `send_keys` without extra actions.

Comment: Daroschchanka, I cannot able to click on that predefined text suggested by drop down list using selenium. Can you help me out of that .

Comment: I have tried many combinations and yours ones also but It cannot able to select the text.

Comment: I am on windows machine

Comment: @AbdulRehman I've rechecked on Windows. This solution works once I've added the explicit wait for the input field. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Its not working at it shows error below, but if you type and select the same world like "EL MONTE"  this one it will turn into blue. I want that functionality through selenium.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Which selenium and chrome version do you use? I'm using Selenium 4, Chrome 97. Comuna textbox field populated for me, but it works only for some text values, e.g. it's populated for __ANCUD__ and shows the error for __Ancud__.

Comment: Selenium version : 3.141.0

Comment: Chrome Version: Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: see the picture again I edited again the question. Have a look please, its showing red error like asking for valid coumne but its a valid one

Comment: Yes, I see. I have the exactly different behavior.. The same - all fields are populated, but no errors.

Comment: but how it can be possible, as you have seen  the picture above , showing me an error on passing the text even like this. Is there any other approach comes to your mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241831/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-abdul-rehman).